# edit Text is not accepting numeric Keyboard in expendable ListVIew

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

here is my code in xml

```
 <EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="0.00"
     android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
     android:textSize="16dp"
     android:id="@+id/et_childinput1"
     android:background="#ffffff"
     android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

i also tried android:numeric="decimal" which is diffracted how can i do this.
i come to know that

```
    android:numeric
    android:phoneNumber
    android:inputMethod
    android:capitalize
    android:autoText
```

are replaced by `android:inputType`

the code above work for me in Edit Text but when it come inside expendable list-view child ,the issue arise there the keyboard arise but again full keyboard is replaced by numeric in a instance
any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you want to add Both text and Numeric value you dont need to apply `inputType` , if you want user to enter only numeric value keep inputType "Numeric" Nothing else or use "numberDecimal" if you think ther can be decimals no need to mention Numeric for it just write numberDecimal

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNoRegEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:ems="15"
                android:hint="Phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="@color/blue_home"/>
```

It may help you

Comment: you are right but when i add the keyboard in expendable list view the numeric keyboard show and in a instant it is replaced with full keyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want only **Numbers** then it may help you

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneNoRegEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:ems="15"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="01234567989"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@color/blue_home"/>
```